# When Application downloaded from AppStore its not installing in IOS 9.X devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode8

I used Xcode 8.2.1 for submission of my Application to AppStore with minimum installation version as 8.

After apple approves the App its not installing in 9.X version.

I didn't change any settings in my App and submitted to [Apple Forms](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/215877#215877)

Please suggest is there any bug in Xcode 8.2.1 ?

Comment: edit your question to show what errors you find in the device console when you attempt to install the app on iOS 9.0.

Comment: Add Targets deployment info screen shot.